# Issues while upgrading GXT 2.3.1a to 4.1.0

Tags: java, extjs, gwt, gxt

Currently we are upgrading from  GWT 2.8.0 to GWT 2.9.0, GXT 2.3.1a to GXT 4.1.0 and also upgraded java 8 to java 11.

We have resolved all the syntax issues by taking the help of [migration doc](https://docs-devel.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/guides/getting_started/migration/Migration2to3.html) provided by sencha.

Once the syntax issues where resolved we got the following error:

```
     [java]    Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.sencha.gxt.theme.base.client.frame.TableFrame.Template'
     [java]       Rebinding com.sencha.gxt.theme.base.client.frame.TableFrame.Template
     [java]          Invoking generator com.sencha.gxt.core.rebind.XTemplatesGenerator
     [java]             [ERROR] Reference could not be found: '65535:["t0","All Methods"],2:["t2","Instance Methods"],8:["t4","Concrete Methods"]'. Please fix the expression in your template.
     [java]    [ERROR] Errors in 'com/sencha/gxt/theme/base/client/frame/TableFrame.java'
     [java]       [ERROR]: Failed to resolve 'com.sencha.gxt.theme.base.client.frame.TableFrame.Template' via deferred binding
     [java]    [WARN] For the following type(s), generated source was never committed (did you forget to call commit()?)
     [java]       [WARN] com.sencha.gxt.theme.base.client.frame.TableFrame_TemplateImpl
     [java]    Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.sencha.gxt.core.client.dom.Layer.LayerTemplates'
     [java]       Rebinding com.sencha.gxt.core.client.dom.Layer.LayerTemplates
     [java]          Invoking generator com.sencha.gxt.core.rebind.XTemplatesGenerator
     [java]             [ERROR] Reference could not be found: '65535:["t0","All Methods"],2:["t2","Instance Methods"],8:["t4","Concrete Methods"]'. Please fix the expression in your template.
     [java]    [ERROR] Errors in 'com/sencha/gxt/core/client/dom/Layer.java'
     [java]       [ERROR]: Failed to resolve 'com.sencha.gxt.core.client.dom.Layer.LayerTemplates' via deferred binding
     [java]    [WARN] For the following type(s), generated source was never committed (did you forget to call commit()?)
     [java]       [WARN] com.sencha.gxt.core.client.dom.Layer_LayerTemplatesImpl
     [java]    Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.sencha.gxt.theme.base.client.frame.NestedDivFrame.Template'
     [java]       Rebinding com.sencha.gxt.theme.base.client.frame.NestedDivFrame.Template
     [java]          Invoking generator com.sencha.gxt.core.rebind.XTemplatesGenerator
     [java]             [ERROR] Reference could not be found: '65535:["t0","All Methods"],2:["t2","Instance Methods"],8:["t4","Concrete Methods"]'. Please fix the expression in your template.
     [java]    [ERROR] Errors in 'com/sencha/gxt/theme/base/client/frame/NestedDivFrame.java'
     [java]       [ERROR]: Failed to resolve 'com.sencha.gxt.theme.base.client.frame.NestedDivFrame.Template' via deferred binding
     [java]    [WARN] For the following type(s), generated source was never committed (did you forget to call commit()?)
     [java]       [WARN] com.sencha.gxt.theme.base.client.frame.NestedDivFrame_TemplateImpl
```

I have already

1. Checked all the POJO and whether serializable was implemented properly.
2. Checked all the imports and removed unwanted.
3. Decompiled the jar and checked whether all the class are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something seems wrong with your build of GXT (or project setup) if you're seeing the string `{65535:["t0","All Methods"],1:["t1","Static Methods"],2:["t2","Instance Methods"],8:["t4","Concrete Methods"]}`. GXT Templates use `{}`s around variable names in HTML strings to know where to interpolate values. So, the templating system thinks it was asked to look for the variable `65535:["t0","All Methods"],1:["t1","Static Methods"],2:["t2","Instance Methods"],8:["t4","Concrete Methods"]`, but that isn't a variable name at all...

Instead, that string is a json object literal that is generated in html files for javadoc. My hunch is that either you've merged the GXT 4 javadoc jar with the normal jar, or you've put the javadoc jar on the classpath, so template files are being read from it instead of from the correct gxt-4.1.0.jar file. Remove the javadoc from your build classpath, and this should be resolved.